# django html regulate input value based on the select option

Tags: html, django

Here the scenario is that  in the html select, there are two options "cube" or "cylinder". and there are three input fields: length, width, and height.

what I am looking for is that when user select "cylinder" option from the dropdown menue, there must require user to input the same value for length and width input fields. if not, when click submitting form, there should be an alert to advise users to make sure both length and width value being the same.

what is the easiest way to do such work?

UPDATE - javascripts for generating the form

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()

    {
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter
    var list_maxField = 9; //Input fields increment limitation

        //Once add button is clicked
    $('.list_add_button').click(function()
        {
        //Check maximum number of input fields
        if(x < list_maxField){
            x++; //Increment field counter
            //var list_fieldHTML = '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><div class="form-group"><input name="list['+x+'][]" type="text" placeholder="Type Item Name" class="form-control"/></div></div><div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7"><div class="form-group"><input name="list['+x+'][]" type="text" placeholder="Type Item Quantity" class="form-control"/></div></div><div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-7 col-md-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list_remove_button btn btn-danger">-</a></div></div>'; //New input field html
            //var list_fieldHTML = '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><div class="form-group"><input name="list['+x+'][]" type="text" placeholder="Type Item Name" class="form-control"/></div></div><div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7"><div class="form-group"><input name="list['+x+'][]" type="text" placeholder="Type Item Quantity" class="form-control"/></div></div><div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-7 col-md-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list_remove_button btn btn-danger">-</a></div></div>'; //New input field html
            var list_fieldHTML = "<div class='row'>"+
            "<span style='margin-left:-3px;'>" + x + "</span>"+
            "<input name='length' required type='text'  placeholder=''  style='width:63px;margin-left:43px;color:gray'/>"+
            "<input name='width' required type='text'  placeholder=''  style='width:63px;margin-left:19px;color:gray'/>"+
            "<input name='height' required type='text'  placeholder=''  style='width:63px;margin-left:19px;color:gray'/>"+
            "<input name='weight' required type='text'  placeholder=''  style='width:63px;margin-left:19px;color:gray'/>"+
            "<input name='quantity' required type='text'  placeholder=''  style='width:63px;margin-left:19px;color:gray'/>"+
            "<select name='typeof'  required  style='width:100px;margin-left:17px;color:gray'>"+
                  "<option value=''>--select--</option>"+
                  "<option value='cube'>cube</option>"+
                  "<option value='cylinder'>cylinder</option>"+
            "</select>"+
            "<select name='updown' required  style='width:100px;margin-left:17px;color:gray'>"+
                  "<option value=''>--select--</option>"+
                  "<option value='true'>true</option>"+
                  "<option value='false'>false</option>"+
            "</select>"+

            "<a href='javascript:void(0);' style='margin-left:33px;' class='list_remove_button btn btn-danger'>-</a>"+
            "</div><p></p>";




            $('.list_wrapper').append(list_fieldHTML); //Add field html
        }
        });

        //Once remove button is clicked
        $('.list_wrapper').on('click', '.list_remove_button', function()
        {
           $(this).closest('div.row').remove(); //Remove field html
           x--; //Decrement field counter
        });
});
</script>
```

the form looks like below format where user can add delete lines for input values depending on the specific situation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in javascript, but that's not particularly robust as someone can easily turn javascript off.  As it is essential validation, and involves multiple fields, you can extend the clean() method of your form.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        length = cleaned_data.get("length")
        width= cleaned_data.get("width")
        type = cleaned_data.get("type")
        if type == "cylinder" and length != width:
            raise ValidationError(
                    "Cylinders must have equal length and width"
                )
```

You can find the relevenat section of the django docs about form validation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/)

If you do want to use javascript, you can do so by writing a function to handle your validation

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
      //get variables from the form
      let length = document.forms["myForm"]["length"].value;
      let width = document.forms["myForm"]["width"].value;
      let type = document.forms["myForm"]["type"].value;
      //do our validation tests
      if (type == "cylinder" && length != width) {
        alert("Cylinders must have equal length and width");
        //if it fails, return false so the form is not submitted.
        return false;
      }
    } 
</script>
```

and then in your form

```
<form name="myForm" action="/formhandler" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

As mentioned, depending on javascript validation is risky, so try and make sure your submitted data is tested server side as well if this is appropriate.

**based on update and comment**

You are going to have problems because all your fields in each row have the same name, so you will need another way to identify them individually if you are going to do comparisons. You will need to do something like:

```
 "<input name="length" id='length_" + x + "' required type='text'  placeholder=''...
 "<input name="width" id='width_" + x + "'required type='text'  placeholder=''...
```

This will give them unique ids.

Then you need to cycle through each group of items and perform the same

```
<script>
    function validateForm(x) {
      //get variables from the form
      for (i = 1; i<=x; i++) {
          let length = document.getElementById("length_" + i).value ].value;
          let width = document.getElementById("width_" + i).value ].value;
          let type = document.getElementById("type" + i).value ].value;
      //do our validation tests
          if (type == "cylinder" && length != width) {
              alert("Cylinders must have equal length and width");
        //if it fails, return false so the form is not submitted.
              return false;
         }
      }
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: I don't use django form. I am using request.POST method. does this work as well? This seems to be validated in the backend after the form is submitted. is it possible to do in the front end directly using html or javascripts code to validate?

Comment: I've updated to provide a simple method of JS validation (your question was tagged with 'django' so I went there first).

Comment: what's the role of action="/formhandler"?

Comment: I tried but not working. because user will input length and width for multiple times (multiple lines depending on how many sizes of items). So in django view.py I used length_list = request.POST.getlist('length')
   width_list  = request.POST.getlist('width') type_list = request.POST.getlist('type'). how to adjust the javascripts to verify each length vs width vs type pairs? i.e. if type_list[0] = "cylinder", then length_list[0] should be same as width_list[0]

Comment: Can you provide code for your form, as the answer will vary depending on how you have set up your fields?

Comment: updated based on update

Comment: only the last values will be submitted, as the others will be overwritten  --- actually I am using request.POST.getlist. so if user add three lines, there will be three elements in the list.

Comment: You are right, of course. I have corrected my answer to use a unique ID for each field so you can preserve your backend use of request.POST.getlist